# React-native android , REST api post error getting "access denied"

Tags: react-native

Developing sample application, when i was call the post method 
    service in componentDidMount() getting  error response access 
    denied. Only android it's having this issue. But I got this 
    response IOS Devices .

- I  researched this case Most of the this issue get an based up on 
  NetWork same wife connection like emulator and my System  this is 
  fine.
- when i was check on AndroidManifest.xml file also getting 
  Internet Permissions also Accessed.But Still getting this Error in 
  Android. Please Solve this ,
- Only getting in Android Device and emulator having this issue
  other Platform device like IOS working fine.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Show some code where your making that post method and also show the error message here.

Comment: okay i will put this

Comment: just add shorter form here, that would do

Comment: but its too long string

Comment: upload that error msg by taking screen shot

Comment: are you there ?

Comment: rowDatanewOrders:{"status":"error","message":"access denied"}

Comment: fetch('https://site:ab4aca652284d7dc87ca1f347f2ac432@ori-eu-west-1.searchly.com/devkoopicafenetecco-2/_search ',{
                         method:'POST',
                         headers:{
                            'Accept':'application/json',
                            'Content-Type':'application/json'
                          },
                          body:JSON.stringify(string)                    }).then((response)=>response.json()).then((responseData)=>{                     
}).catch((err)=>{
                          console.error(err)
                        })

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151568/discussion-between-ravi-raj-and-lavaraju).

Answer (score 0):

If the REST server is on localhost in Android you'll have to use your IP instead of http://localhost.

If the rest server is not on localhost you might have to adjust the body and the headers. So instead of string body use a json object etc.

Your code:

> fetch('site:ab4aca652284d7dc87ca1f347f2ac432@ori-eu-west-1.s‌​‌​earchly.co…
>   ',{ method:'POST', headers:{ 'Accept':'application/json',
>   'Content-Type':'application/json' }, body:JSON.stringify(string)
>   }).then((response)=>response.json()).then((responseData)=>{
>   }).catch((err)=>{ console.error(err) })
>   rowDatanewOrders:{"status":"error","message":"access denied"}

make sure you have a valid json in body if you have the header `'Content-Type':'application/json'`, not a string as you have now!

more details about possible adjustments of the body and headers here:
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/5222

Comment: i didn't get your Point can you give it sample

Comment: If the server is on localhost, instead of doing a post to http://localhost:3000/records you'll have to make the post to http://<your-ip>:3000/records. If you server is not on localhost, post a detailed description of your error and the code

Comment: fetch('site:ab4aca652284d7dc87ca1f347f2ac432@ori-eu-west-1.s‌​earchly.co… ',{ method:'POST', headers:{ 'Accept':'application/json', 'Content-Type':'application/json' }, body:JSON.stringify(string) }).then((response)=>response.json()).then((responseData)=>{ }).catch((err)=>{ console.error(err) }) 

rowDatanewOrders:{"status":"error","message":"access denied"}